# Get the number of columns of a table

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Consider the following plots

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document} 

\pgfplotstableread{
1 3 6 4
2 2 5 2
3 4 4 1
4 5 2 3
}\table

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,3}{%
      \addplot table[x index=0,y index=\i] {\table};
                            }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to use it as a template for input files of varying number of columns.
For this I need to replace the `3` ine the `foreach` command by the number of columns of the loaded table.
Is there something similar to `\pgfplotstablecols` that would be understood in this environment?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is `\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{<table>}`, which stores the number of columns of the given table in the macro `\pgfplotsretval`. You'll need to subtract one from this number to get the correct index of the last column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document} 

\pgfplotstableread{
1 3 6 4 2
2 2 5 2 1
3 4 4 1 5
4 5 2 3 1
}\table

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\table}
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval-1}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\pgfmathresult}{%
      \addplot table[x index=0,y index=\i] {\table};
                            }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```